# Bad performance function in PHP. With large files memory blows up! How can I refactor?

Tags: php, performance, function

I have a function that strips out lines from files. I'm handling with large files(more than 100Mb). I have the PHP Memory with 256MB but the function that handles with the strip out of lines blows up with a 100MB CSV File.

What the function must do is this:

Originally I have the CSV like:

> Copyright (c) 2007 MaxMind LLC.  All
>   Rights Reserved.
>   locId,country,region,city,postalCode,latitude,longitude,metroCode,areaCode
>   1,"O1","","","",0.0000,0.0000,,
>   2,"AP","","","",35.0000,105.0000,,
>   3,"EU","","","",47.0000,8.0000,,
>   4,"AD","","","",42.5000,1.5000,,
>   5,"AE","","","",24.0000,54.0000,,
>   6,"AF","","","",33.0000,65.0000,,
>   7,"AG","","","",17.0500,-61.8000,,
>   8,"AI","","","",18.2500,-63.1667,,
>   9,"AL","","","",41.0000,20.0000,,

When I pass the CSV file to this function I got:

> locId,country,region,city,postalCode,latitude,longitude,metroCode,areaCode
>   1,"O1","","","",0.0000,0.0000,,
>   2,"AP","","","",35.0000,105.0000,,
>   3,"EU","","","",47.0000,8.0000,,
>   4,"AD","","","",42.5000,1.5000,,
>   5,"AE","","","",24.0000,54.0000,,
>   6,"AF","","","",33.0000,65.0000,,
>   7,"AG","","","",17.0500,-61.8000,,
>   8,"AI","","","",18.2500,-63.1667,,
>   9,"AL","","","",41.0000,20.0000,,

It only strips out the first line, nothing more. The problem is the performance of this function with large files, it blows up the memory.

The function is:

```
 public function deleteLine($line_no, $csvFileName) {

  // this function strips a specific line from a file
  // if a line is stripped, functions returns True else false
  //
  // e.g.
  // deleteLine(-1, xyz.csv); // strip last line
  // deleteLine(1, xyz.csv); // strip first line

  // Assigna o nome do ficheiro
  $filename = $csvFileName;

  $strip_return=FALSE;

  $data=file($filename);
  $pipe=fopen($filename,'w');
  $size=count($data);

  if($line_no==-1) $skip=$size-1;
  else $skip=$line_no-1;

  for($line=0;$line<$size;$line++)
   if($line!=$skip)
    fputs($pipe,$data[$line]);
   else
    $strip_return=TRUE;

  return $strip_return;
 }
```

It is possible to refactor this function to not blow up with the 256MB PHP Memory?

Give me some clues.

Best Regards,

Comment: you could start by not reading the ENTIRE file into memory with file(). Read it line by line, and write back to disk when you're done with a line.

Comment: When you have your own server think about doing it with `perl` or `sed` ;-).

Comment: My lazy man approach to this problem is to add this line: ini_set('memory_limit','1000M');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem for your blowout is the `file` function that brings the entire file in memory. To overcome this you need to read the file line by line, write all but the line to be deleted to a temporary file and finally rename the temporary file.

```
public function deleteLine($line_no, $csvFileName) {

        // get a temp file name in current working directory..you can use
        // any other directory say /tmp
        $tmpFileName = tempnam(".", "csv");

        $strip_return=FALSE;

        // open input file for reading.
        $readFD=fopen($csvFileName,'r');

        // temp file for writing.
        $writeFD=fopen($tmpFileName,'w');

        // check for fopen errors.

        if($line_no==-1) {
                $skip=$size-1;
        } else {
                $skip=$line_no-1;
        }

        $line = 0;

        // read lines from input file one by one.
        // write all lines except the line to be deleted.
        while (($buffer = fgets($readFD)) !== false) {
                if($line!=$skip)
                        fputs($writeFD,$buffer);
                else
                        $strip_return=TRUE;
                $line++;
        }

        // rename temp file to input file.    
        rename($tmpFileName,$csvFileName);

        return $strip_return;
}
```

Comment: Hi, this function works well. Only fails in renaming the files. It gives me this error: Warning: rename(C:\xampp\htdocs\testes\csv1E2.tmp,C:\xampp\htdocs\testes\GeoLite
City-Blocks.csv): Bad file descriptor in ...

Answer (score 1):

well, the easiest answer is don't do it with PHP. Seriously, `sed` would work much better for this because the whole file would never be in memory. Check out these [oneliners](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sed1line.txt), but essentially:

```
sed '1d' filename
```

I know system calls are frowned upon, but I think this may be a case when one is warranted.

Answer (score 0):

The [file()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) method reads an entire file into an array, all at once.  I would imagine this is where things blow up.  You probably want to have a second fopen() handle for your input file so you can read one line at a time.

If your requirement is to handle this task with PHP, that's fine.  But this type of thing is probably better left to something like [awk](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=awk)