# PHP file_get_contents return 404 with existing page

Tags: json, php

I'm downloading HTML table from remote server, with file_get_contents which get around 25mb.
But the server start loading the page and then respond with error 404. I have checked many times and html page is accessible without problems.
I have done some test with other pages on the same server and they are working but the size of them is much smaller, around 3mb.

In php.ini file max_file_size is set to 128mb, i tried with 256mb but no changes.

Comment: `max_file_size` is for uploading. Maybe your server is timing out. Set `max_execution_time` to something higher.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4501757/bad-performance-function-in-php-with-large-files-memory-blows-up-how-can-i-ref

Comment: Set maximum execution time 0 in your htaccess file like this: php_value max_execution_time 0

Comment: max_execution_time is 30 sec. i think thats more than enough. And memory_limit is 128mb

Comment: Also i'm using nginx.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility might be that your php is hitting the max_execution_time

Please [check this in order to manipulate this variable](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)

You can set this up in your php.ini file also ( depending on how you host your script )

Also check your apache error log and see what can cause this.

Are you sure it's 404 and not 500 internal error ?

Answer (score 0):

Solved, it was limited by nginx. I changed fastcgi_read_timeout to 300;